# Is there a chance that this will still work after replacing the capacitors?

Tags: capacitor, pcb

PCB from an acer monitor. I just plugged it in and it went up in smoke. i opened it up and saw that the capacitor is leaking fluid. will this burnt pcb still work?

[image: PCB from an acer monitor. I just plugged it in and it went up in smoke. i opened it up and saw that the capacitor is leaking fluid. will this burnt pcb still work?]

[image: capacitor leaking fluid]

Comment: No. I see at least one IC exploded, a few resistors also exploded (apparently the trace also exploded). So the problem is far from being just on the capacitor. Even if you fixed the visually damaged parts, there is a high chance that other components are also damaged.

Comment: Was this an old monitor? But surface mount components, so it can't be many decades old. I guess that's why they recommend to hook up old equipment to current limiting power sources first to prevent the damage from exploding electrolytic capacitors.

Comment: its an ACER AL1916w. I actually plugged it into an APC surt2000xli UPS. Surprised it happened. Kinda sad to hear that this is dead. I was looking forward to a DIY to fix this :(

Comment: you can still use the board for soldering practice

Answer (score 1):

No. There are blown chips so only replacing capacitors won't help at all.